# NSMutablearray cannot converted to a valid url - react native

Tags: react-native

I am facing the error mentioned in the title. I tried to add `toString()` method but it doesn't resolve the issue. I wrote `uri` instead of `url` but nothing worked.

my code:

```
const images = [
    "http://localhost/media/categories/Butchies-2_EuH4UEC.jpg",
    "http://localhost/media/categories/original_cq43Fci.jpg",
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <ScrollView>
        {images.map((i, index) => (
          <Image key={index} source={{ url: i }} style={styles.banner} />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
```

Comment: try changing url to uri inside the image tag source

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working my friend. source should be `uri` only. Run below code and check once.

```
    const imagesArray = [
        'https://reactnative.dev/img/header_logo.png',
        'https://reactnative.dev/img/header_logo.png',
        'https://reactnative.dev/img/header_logo.png'
    ]
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1,}}>
            {
                imagesArray.map((image, index) => (
                        <Image key={index} style={{ height: 40, width: 40, tintColor: 'blue' }} source={{ uri: image }} />
                    )
                )
            }
        </View>
    )
```